# jquerymobile eval with object parameter missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

This handler doesn't like the $page parameter in the eval function, getting error "missing ] after element list" is there anyway to pass this parameter through?

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pageinit pagebeforeshow pageshow pagebeforehide pagehide', function (event, ui) {
    var $page = $(this);
    var type = event.type.replace('page', 'Page').replace('init', 'Init').replace('before', 'Before').replace('show', 'Show').replace('hide', 'Hide');
    eval('Controller.Method.' + type + '(' + $page + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forcing `$page` to be part of a string, which doesn't quite work because it's a jQuery object. The string will be `[object Object]` because there is no better string representation for a jQuery object.

This is exactly a case in which to **avoid** using `eval`. This should work, and is cleaner and safer:

```
Controller.Method[type]($page);
```

Comment: Wow thankyou! Never knew you could use square bracekts, what is called when one utilises that? I'd like to learn more about it

Comment: @Baconbeastnz: It's nothing fancy really. `a.b` is the same as `a['b']` - with the latter you can also use a variable instead (such as `a[variable]`), which isn't possible with the first method.

Comment: I've just found out, on the other end of this function, I've got a slightly harder task to achieve, in this scenario, the first object name is coming in dynamically. So, I'm guessing the only way to access this by using our last method would be to reference it from some sort of global JS object...

Comment: @Baconbeastnz: You mean the name `Controller` is unknown? `window.Controller` may work (or using the `[]` notation).

Comment: window worked! awesome. Might be worth cross browser testing this, but looks good